# sed: How to add a key/value pair at the end of the section in INI file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, ini

In order to add a key/value pair at the end of the section in INI file, I would like to:

1. Find the match section name and check if next square bracket (i.e. ^[) is available. If so, find the last occurrence of key/value pair within these lines (i.e. from match section name to next square bracket). Insert the key/value pair at the end of last occurrence of key/value pair.
2. Append the key/value pair to the end of the file if next square bracket is not available.

For case (1), I can use sed to check if next square bracket is available, i.e.

```
sed -i -e "/^\[$section\]/,/^\[.*\]/ ..."
```

However, I have no idea how to match the last occurrence of key=value. The reason of matching the last occurrence (instead of adding ke/value pair just before next square bracket) is because I can choose to introduce newline or not before the new key/value pair in the INI file. For example, if I want to add key10=value10

```
[section1]
...
key8=value8
key9=value9
\n (could be multiple newline)
[section2]
```

It becomes

```
[section1]
...
key8=value8
key9=value9
\n (optional)
key10=value10
\n (could be multiple newline)
[section2]
```

Please could you kindly suggest how can I achieve this?

Comment: could you post the expected output?

Comment: Why is there a `\n` ? Are there not newlines betweens the key value pairs ?

Comment: I would like to make newline optional to insert in between key/value pairs

Comment: you choose to add `\n` if needed (missing in section) or other criteria? in fact, can we assume that the section ended with a `\n`, or a new square bracket section or EOF

Comment: Consider you have different styles of writing an INI file. Some people tends to put newline in between key/value pairs whilst some don't (it could be multiple newline at the end of one section and before the beginning of next section). So the main idea is to match the last occurrence of key/value pair instead of matching newline.

Comment: @anubhava: I want to insert the new key/value pair just after the last occurrence of key/value pair without extra newline to make the style of writing INI file more consistent (i.e. if there are one newline in between, then insert a newline; otherwise no newline will be added).

Comment: I have seen many `ini` files and IMO inserting new key-value using my approach doesn't break any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of completeness (and because sed hackery is mindbendy fun), you can do it with sed like this:

```
/^\[section1\]/,/^\[/ {
  x
  /^$/ !{ x; H }
  /^$/  { x; h }
  d
}
x
/^\[section1\]/ {
  s/\(\n\+[^\n]*\)$/\nkey10=value10\1/
  p
  x
  p
  x
  d
}
x
p
```

Put that in a file, say `foo.sed`, and run `sed -n -f foo.sed foo.ini`. Or, if you prefer,

```
sed '/^\[section1\]/,/^\[/ { x; /^$/ !{ x; H }; /^$/ { x; h; }; d; }; x; /^\[section1\]/ { s/\(\n\+[^\n]*\)$/\nkey10=value10\1/; p; x; p; x; d }; x' foo.ini
```

...as if it wasn't hard enough to read already.

This is fun with the hold buffer; the first bit matches all lines from `[section1]` to the beginning of the next section and puts then all in the hold buffer (and breaks out there). If we're not in that section, the rest swaps in the hold buffer, checks if section1 is in it, if so substitutes `key10=value10` into it at the appropriate position, prints it, swaps the pattern space back, prints it, swaps the hold space back and deletes it (now the line after section1 is in the hold buffer, but we don't care about it anymore). The rest of the time, the pattern space is just swapped back and printed, so from there it works like `cat`.

EDIT: NeronLeVelu pointed out that this only works if there is a section after `[section1]` that the pattern range can match. Where this is not guaranteed, special handling for the last line is needed in case section1 hasn't been handled by then. This can do it:

```
$ {
  H
  x
  /^\[section1\]/ {
    s/\n\+$//
    a key10=value10
    x
  }
  x
  p
  d
}
/^\[section1\]/,/^\[/ {
  x
  /^$/ !{ x; H }
  /^$/  { x; h }
  d
}
x
/^\[section1\]/ {
  s/\(\n\+[^\n]*\)$/\nkey10=value10\1/
  p
  x
  p
  x
  d
}
x
p
```

This will handle the last line differently from the rest; it'll append it to the hold buffer, check if section1 still needs handling, if so append `key10=value10` and swap back, then swap back again and print what is then the pattern space. This confusing bit of shunting means that if section1 is still in the hold buffer, then the hold buffer is printed, and otherwise the last line as it came in.

By this point, I feel compelled to point out that once a sed script has become this long, it is worth considering other options.

Comment: does it works on section ending ? (cannot test here, no GNU sed)

Comment: You mean when section1 is the last section? You have a point there. Give me a minute.

Comment: Damn dude, 8 year old answer safed me hours of work. Thanks, what a sick sed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v sec='[section1]' -v kv='key10=value10' 'p && $1~/\[[^]]*\]/{p=0; print kv} 
           $1==sec{p=1} END{if (p) print kv} 1' file
[section1]
...
key8=value8
key9=value9

key10=value10
[section2]
```

Comment: It complains "awk: line 1: runaway regular expression /\[.*\]{p=0 ..."

Comment: @anubhava Typo: there is (not:) a missing '/' at the end of the regex.

Comment: I think it was just the slipped '/' because mawk is very standard... (not too much extensions, but very close to standard)

Comment: It is possible to add this just after key9=value9 without extra newline? (i.e. matching the last occurrence of key/value pair)?

Comment: @chesschi: May be possible but won't be that easy. And for something which is **already working** otherwise you may not want to add too much complexity for cosmetic reasons.

Comment: I tried your command with some INI file and it won't work. The one I tried is no newline in between key/value pairs except the end of the section

Comment: @anubhava why `index($1, "[")` instead of `/^\[/`. And i realised that(about sec) and deleted my comment,sorry!

Comment: @Jidder: Originally I had `$1~/\[[^]]*\]/` but due to my un-surety about `mawk` I changed it to `index` function (reverted it back now). chesschi:  If you provide an ini file for which it doesn't work then I can look into that.

Comment: `awk -v sec='[Section1]' -v kv='key10=value10' 'p && $1~/\[[^]]*\]/{p=0; print kv} $1==sec{p=1} END{if (p) print kv} 1' file.ini` command worked as long as ini file has a section called `[Section1]`.

Comment: @chesschi toupper both of them `toupper($1)==toupper(sec)`

Comment: thanks for your effort but I would prefer without extra newline as explained earlier

Answer (score 0):

Another hacky awk way

```
awk -v k='key10=value10' '($1=="[section1]"||x&&/^\[/)&&!(x=!x){print k}
                           END{if(x)print k}1' file
```

Checks if field one equals `[section1]` or if x is not 0.
If either of these are true,sets x to the inverse of x and checks if it is 0.
If it is 0 then it prints the keyvalue pair.
At the end if x is still set then it prints the keyvalue pair.
1 to print all lines

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '/^\[section1]/,/^\[/ {
   $ a\
key10=value10
   /^\[section1]/ !{
      /[^=#]\{1,\}=/ !i\
key10=value10
      }
   }' YourFile
```

- posix version for pattern so add `--posix`on GNU sed
- change the 2 occurence of `[section1]` name to select the wanted section
- adapt the 2 lines `key10=value10` for your key/value peer
- add into section after the 'first' line with non key/value peer in a section (and case of the last line that is the selected section also)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inventing a barely round and fragile wheel with sed I recommend using a [dedicated program](https://github.com/pixelb/crudini) specifically made to manipulate ini files which is dead simple to use:

```
$ cat test.conf | tee test.conf.orig
[section1]
##...
key8=value8
key9=value9





[section2]
abc=123
$ crudini --set test.conf section1 key10 value10
$ diff -u test.conf.orig test.conf
--- test.conf.orig      2017-10-10 20:59:55.205678995 +0200
+++ test.conf   2017-10-10 21:00:00.831477388 +0200
@@ -2,6 +2,7 @@
 ##...
 key8=value8
 key9=value9
+key10 = value10



$
```